# How to check Mouse enter event is already in progress?

Tags: jquery

```
$("li").mouseenter(function () { 
    $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, 300);
    $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, 300);
});
```

How to check whether previous event has completed it's action or not. As it is being firing no of times I entered mouse in the list item. which makes it 300*10 if I enter mouse 10 times. Any Solution...

Answer (score 2):

Set your own flag.

```
   var mouseOn = 0
    $("li").mouseenter(function () {
        if(mouseOn==1) {
           ....
        }
        mouseOn = 1;
        $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, 300);
        $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, 300);
    });
```